# In pandas, why I am getting error like "'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'Mean'

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe with 2 columns and I am applying 'groupby' as per one column. Now I want to get the aggregate value for 'Sum', "Maximum' and "Minimum" using:

```
df.groupby(["Column1"]).agg(
    {"Column2": ["sum","max","Mean", lambda x : x.max() - x.min()]}
)
```

Giving error as:

AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'Mean'

Applying `groupby()`function

```
df.groupby(["Column1"]).agg(
    {"Column2": ["sum","max","Mean", lambda x : x.max() - x.min()]}
```

Expected output:
SUM     Max    Mean
Value1 of column1 -- XXX    YYY   ZZZ
Value1 of column1--  PQR   STU     VWX

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you format your question a little better?  Newlines are helpful to help people read, and code should be in `codeblocks`.  See our [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) guide!

Answer (score 2):

I think you got it in upper case. Just to get the mean, I tried this code and it seems to work. Correct me if I am misunderstanding something here.

```
A=[1,1,3,4,3]
B=[6,7,8,9,10]
C=[8,9,101,1,2]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[A,B,C]).T
df.groupby(by=[0]).agg(['mean','min'])
```